# What is the proper way of doing partial matches in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a `Properties` object, and want to do something if the configuration contains a specific key. If this key does not exist, I simply want to ignore it. I tried it the following way:

```
myProps getProperty "foo" match {
  case v if v != null => doSomethingWith v
}
```

but this causes a `MatchError` if the properties object does not contain `foo`.

I can think of two ways to tackle this. Approach 1 is:

```
myProps getProperty "foo" match {
  case v if v != null => doSomethingWith v
  case _ => // ignore if foo does not exist
}
```

Approach 2 is:

```
if(myProps containsKey "foo") doSomethingWith(myProps getProperty "foo")
```

Personally, I like approach 1 better because it queries the `Properties` only once and the comment tells that a non-match is intentionally ignored, but this is also quite verbose. Approach 2 has the flaw that, besides from querying the `Properties` twice, if in the near future the key is changed, it has to be changed at two places here which is a source of bugs.

So, is there a better way to do it like approach 1, but shorter, or is this the way it is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your function in `Option`.

```
Option(myProps getProperty "foo").map {
    v => doSomethingWith v
}
```

`Option(myProps getProperty "foo")` will return either `Some(propertyValue)` or `None`. Only if the result is `Some(propertyValue)`,  `doSomethingWith (v)` in the code will be executed. If it is None, it will be ignored.

You can also have a default value in case the result is None by using `getOrElse` function on the `Option`.

As mentioned in comments by @VladimirMatveev, `map` is not the right thing to do, if the method `doSomethingWith` has side effects. Use `foreach` instead.

Comment: As a general rule, if you're calling a Java method that may return `null`, you should *always* coerce it to the correct type by wrapping it in `Option(...)`.

Comment: if you myProps is of type Map, you can use the method get, to get an option, so you do not need to do the wrapping yourself

Comment: No-no-no, if `doSomethingWith` has side effects, which appears to be the case, you don't use `map`, you use `foreach`. Operational difference here is little, but semantic difference is huge.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev - Agreed. Updated the answer